# Что происходит, когда я переинициализирую коллекцию?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Есть у меня коллекция строк. В ней, скажем, 5 строк. И тут я решил её взять и переинициализировать.

```
ArrayList<String> lines = splitByLines(textFile);
lines = splitByLines(anotherTextFile);
```

Как я понял, последовательность следующая:

1. Ссылке `lines` присвоен другой объект, а тот который был в ней - стал недоступен.
2. Сборщик мусора (через некоторое время) уничтожает коллекцию и все строки, которые были внутри.

А вообще хорошо ли так делать? Можно ли надеяться на сборщик мусора? Если в коллекции было скажем миллиард строк, то пока он недоступный лежит в "куче" он делают "утечку памяти"?

Будет ли лучше сделать так?

```
lines.clear()
lines.addAll(splitByLines(anotherTextFile));
```

Comment: "утечка памяти" - это если GC вообще не собирается очищать эту память. А просто "GC очистит эту память, когда появится необходимость" - это нормальный вариант. Ведь когда "прижмёт" (а может, и раньше), память будет освобождена

Comment: `lines.clear()`, кстати, коллекцию-то очистит, но сами строки из памяти ведь никуда не денутся

Comment: @Regent, ага. А всмысле, никуда не денутся?) Очистка коллекции разве их не удалит?

Comment: @Flippy удалит, когда GC этого захочет (:

Comment: А если это строки из внутреннего кеша, то может и вовсе не удалить )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последовательность может быть немного не такой. Мы ведь не знаем что внутри метода `splitByLines()`. Он может напрямую работать с instance-переменной `lines` и в конце ее же возвращать (очень некрасиво так делать, но я видел такой код в продакшине!!!).
По поводу очистки списка и добавления. Метод ArrayList.`clear()` всего лишь об-`null`-яет все ячейки и присваивает `0` свойству `size` и НИКОИМ ОБРАЗОМ не уменьшает автоматически свойство `capacity`! Есть ручной метод `shrinkToSize()`, но надо не забыть его вызвать. Но даже если так сделать, то произойдет следующее:

1. Очистили лист (память не уменьшилась, см. выше).
2. Отработал метод `splitByLines()` - пусть отработал правильно, внутри себя создал новый лист, заполнил его и вернул.
3. Каждый элемент нового списка скопировали в старый (`lines`).

Потом работает `gc`. Как видим, по памяти выигрыша нет, но поимели трабл с производительностью при добавлении элементов.

Comment: Во как! Вроде бы обычный код, а столько коварности))

Comment: Да никакой коварности, если понимать как все происходит :)

Comment: Спасибо за обьяснение) Это я решился перечитать книгу (уже 6 раз!) с каждым прочтением узнаю все больше, сейчас вот читаю про сборщик мусора, только сейчас начинаю что-то понимать